# affected_rows always returns int(0)

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to know how many rows gets updated, but function "affected_rows" always returns 0. This is my code:

```
$this->connect = new mysqli("mysql.xxx.com","root","mypass","site") or die("error on connect");
$update = $this->connect->query($query);
if($update === true){
    $this->html .= '<table class="select-result"><tr><td>Affected rows: '.$this->connect->affected_rows.'</td></tr></table>';
}

var_dump($this->connect->affected_rows); //Returns int(0)
```

And this is my query:

```
update customers set comment='a' where id=1;
```

[image]

This query updates the row in DB, but php function `$this->connect->affected_rows` returns zero. Any idea?

Comment: Idea: what about reading this function's description in manual?

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you. You really helped, I would never have thought of.

Comment: @bansi edited. There should not be var_dump. Just misprint.

Comment: @CurtisW vabieble $update just can be true or false. It's boolean var, not object.

Comment: is there really a change happening in the database? try changing to `comment='b'` and see if it returns value other than `0` on the first execution?

Comment: @bansi, yes it's realy changes the row.

Comment: @RyanVincent take a look at the picture

Comment: @RyanVincent, $this->html .= '<table class="select-result"><tr><td>Affected rows: '.$this->connect->affected_rows.'</td></tr></table>';

Look carefully at the code at the top of the post